# What consequences does spamming a DynamoDB table with invalid keys have?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I have a list of id and for each of them I'm fetching the corresponding item from a DynamoDB table using `GetItem`.

The thing is some ids are not present.

My question is: Let's say if I go through my list, there are 5000 ids that doesn't match any item in table, and I make each call with a 2 seconds delay between each of them.

What should I expect to happen to my table ?

```
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const getItem = (key) => {
  const getParams = {
    TableName: 'my-table',
    Key: {
      id: key
    }
  };

  return dynamo
    .get(getParams)
    .promise()
    .then(result => {
      const item = result.Item;
      if(item){
        return Promise.resolve(item);
      }

      return Promise.reject();
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Could not retrieve item with id', key);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well nothing will happen to DynamoDB Table. It will still serve normally. It's very scalable and fast. But, attention here if you missed that. This might trick you into increasing costs ->

> If you perform a read operation on an item that does not exist,
>   DynamoDB still consumes provisioned read throughput: A strongly
>   consistent read request consumes one read capacity unit, while an
>   eventually consistent read request consumes 0.5 of a read capacity
>   unit.

[See here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ItemSizeCalculations.Reads)